# Can I specify redirects and pipes in variables?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that creates a Subversion patch file for the current directory. I want to modify it to zip the produced file, if `-z` is given as an argument to the script.

Here's the relevant part:

```
zipped=''
zipcommand='>'

if [ "$1" = "-z" ]
then
   zipped='zipped '
   filename="${filename}.zip"
   zipcommand='| zip >'
fi

echo "Creating ${zipped}patch file $filename..."

svn diff $zipcommand $filename
```

This doesn't work because it passes the `|` or `>` contained in `$zipcommand` as an argument to `svn`.

I can easily work around this, but the question is whether it's ever possible to use these kinds of operators when they're contained in variables.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do something like this (use bash -c or eval):

```
zipped=''
zipcommand='>'

if [ "$1" = "-z" ]
then
   zipped='zipped '
   filename="${filename}.zip"
   zipcommand='| zip -@'
fi

echo "Creating ${zipped}patch file $filename..."

eval "svn diff $zipcommand $filename"
# this also works: 
# bash -c "svn diff $zipcommand $filename"
```

This appears to work, but my version of zip (Mac OS X) required that i change the line:

```
zipcommand='| zip -@'
```

to

```
zipcommand='| zip - - >'
```

Edit: incorporated @DanielBungert's suggestion to use eval

Comment: Thanks!

And yeah, I had the wrong zip arguments originally, as I had adapted this from a script that piped the files given by "svn status" into "zip -@" which reads filenames from stdin.

Answer (score 2):

eval is what you are looking for.

```
# eval 'printf "foo\nbar" | grep bar'
bar
```

Be careful with quote characters on that.

Answer (score 0):

Or you should try `zsh` shell whic allows to define global aliases, e.g.:

```
alias -g L='| less'
alias -g S='| sort'
alias -g U='| uniq -c'
```

Then use this command (which is somewhat cryptic for the ones who took a look from behind ;-) )

```
./somecommand.sh S U L
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Open a new file handle on either a process substitution to handle the compression or on the named file. Then redirect the output of `svn diff` to that file handle.

```
if [ "$1" = "-z" ]; then
    zipped='zipped '
    filename=$filename.zip
    exec 3> >(zip > "$filename")
else
    exec 3> "$filename"
fi

echo "Creating ${zipped}patch file $filename"
svn diff >&3
```